# Creating buttons on an image in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, button

I am creating a website of a map of South-East Asia. I want the user be able to press on country on the map and a pop up box will come up showing information of the country pressed on.

How will I make the buttons on the map work? I have tried to transparent the countries in different images and overlay them in HTML and CSS however this did not work

Comment: please descripe closer what you mean by "this did not work". Show the code of what you have tried and what you are struggeling to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an image map. Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Comment: Add this function as a click event to each `area` element: `function clickArea(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); window.alert(evt.target.alt); }`

Answer (score 0):

img map area are exactly for this. You can mix it with css and js if you need to add/remove classes on hover, like hide/show the country hover.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the most common method of doing this is by using an image map. However, if you would like an alternative that is a little more interactive you could use jQuery. There are a number of jQuery map / floorplan plugins that can achieve this elegantly.

Here are a few I have found from a simple Google search:

JVectorMap - [visit](http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/world/)

mapSVG - [visit](http://map.karaliki.ru/)

JQVMAP - [visit](http://jqvmap.com/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to solve this with `SVG`.

It gives you not only an ability to define complex shapes (and also export code from ex. illustrator) but also to make your UI more user-friendly (color overlays, outlines etc).